# Can not find or remember exchange

Tags: wallet, exchanges, wallet-recovery, lost-wallet

About 4 years ago i gave my son some BTC for his Birthday....
Trying to teach him a bit of financial responsibility.....
he created a wallet, on an exchange i believe, i wasnt part of that, as i insisted he take charge and responsibilty for his own, and, keep passwords, seed etc safe.

Fast forward till now..... He can not remember which exchange he created the wallet on, i do have the original wallet numbers however...... dont have seed.
it there anyway to tell which exchange it went to , he " thought he saved all the info on his computer..... kids huh.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406

Answer (score 0):

> **[is] there anyway to tell which exchange it went to**

In general it isn't possible.

> **i do have the original wallet numbers**

Wallet numbers aren't really a thing, there are wallet-IDs for some custodial wallets and there are Bitcoin-addresses for normal wallets.

If the number has hyphens in it, that might be a [Wallet ID](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000813966-What-is-a-wallet-ID-) for an account at blockchain.com. In which case their support *might* be able to help.

If the number looks like a [Bitcoin address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Invoice_address), it isn't generally possible to trace those anywhere useful and you can't recover control from an address alone.

There are specialist businesses that perform blockchain analysis to try to infer relationships between addresses and to infer ownership of addresses. They are probably expensive to use and probably do not find anything useful in most cases.

It may be better to look for email or other text messages relating to a possible custodial account.